# why am i getting 'none' in the output

Tags: python, function

''''why am i getting 'none' in the output

def foo(temp):
if temp > 25:
x= print('hot')

```
elif temp >15 and temp < 25 :
     x= print('warm')
     
   

elif temp <15 :
    x = print('cold')
   
return x
```

print(foo(66))

***output***
hot
None

''''''

Comment: Because ```print``` returns ```None```. You are doing ```x=print(...``` which evaluates to ```x=None```

Comment: What do you think `x` *should* be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `print` returns Nothing or `None`. So when you do `x = print(...)`, it is assigning the returned value of `print` to `x` which is `None`

Then when you do `return x`, you are doing `return None` which is getting printed.